# Can someone explain to me how this appending a table with ajax works?

Tags: php, ajax, server-side, tablesorter

So I am using Mottie's fork of the tablesorter plug in and it has been working well for me. However I have a couple pages that will have some large records of data that I need to deal with. So I assume the best way of going about this is using AJAX to fill the table. There is an example in the documentation but I do not know javascript or ajax very well so I am not sure exactly how it is working.

http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-ajax.html

A couple specific questions would be.

What would the code on `assets/ajax-content.html` look like? that is the piece I really wanted to know about. how it is actually getting the records and sending them back.

I also just don't fully understand how the

```
("#ajax-append").click(function()
```

is working.  how is it receiving the 'html' parameter on the line

```
$.get("assets/ajax-content.html", function(html) {
```

Any help is really appreciated. thanks

Comment: `$.get()`... it's doing an ajax request to the server. that function(html) is the CALLBACK that the ajax code will invoke when the ajax call gets a response from the server, and the callback's argument is the text received from the server. in other words, RTFM: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: ok so what would the ajax processing page look like? like what format is the text getting sent back in etc. I am just finding this all confusing right now so sorry for any silly questions.

Comment: there is no ajax processing page. it's just fetching some static html from the server, and directly inserting it into the dom. but there's no reason the ajax handling script can't be a script or other program. remember that ajax is just a plain-jane-nothing-special http request that happens to be performed by code in the background of a page.

Comment: do you know of any examples or tutorials I can use that will show me how to go about using SQL to get the records then send them back to the page?  like if I have $.get("assets/ajax-content.php", function(html)  and then on the ajax-content.php page have all the code for getting the data off the database and then send it back to the table.

Comment: there's plenty online, and this site is FULL of sql-type questions.

Comment: I guess I am just confused as to what format it needs to be sent back in

Comment: that's entirely up to your code. if your code prefers json, then the script should send json. if it wants xml, send xml, blah blah blah.

Comment: I just assumed the plugin would want the data back formatted in a specific way in order to use it.

Answer (score 1):

From the examples, we can determine it's returning HTML. So your back-end script would want to do the same. From the example page, the `tbody` contains the following:

```
<tr>
  <td>Bruce</td>
  <td>Evans</td>
  <td>22</td>
  <td>$13.19</td>
  <td>11%</td>
  <td>Jan 18, 2007 9:12 AM</td>
</tr>
```

So when we click the link (`<a href="#" id="ajax-append">Append new table data</a>`) in the example, we append more Table Rows to the Table Body. We can only hope that what it wants is more of the same. An example could be:

```
<?php
// connect to DB
// run query
// get recordset
// output recordset in Table Row format
while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc($results)){
  echo "<tr>\r\n";
  echo "\t<td>{$row['fname']}</td>\r\n";
  echo "\t<td>{$row['lname']}</td>\r\n";
  echo "\t<td>{$row['age']}</td>\r\n";
  echo "\t<td>{$row['total']}</td>\r\n";
  echo "\t<td>{$row['discount']}</td>\r\n";
  echo "\t<td>{$row['date']}</td>\r\n";
  echo "</tr>\r\n";
}
$sql->close();
?>
```